# TradingView Pine Plot Arrow Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Editor and I'm having some issues mapping out my strategy. I have a few conditions / confirmations that have to be met in order to plot a green up arrow below the candle for a long position.

Below is my current code, but I keep receiving the same error "**line 75: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope.**"

Any help is appreciated!

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Directional Movement Index", shorttitle="DMI", format=format.price, precision=4, overlay=true)

// Setup DMI Indicator
len = input(5, minval=1, title="DI Length")
lensig = input(1, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)

up = change(high)
down = -change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = rma(tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)

// Setup MACD 1
[macdLine_1, signalLine_1, histLine_1] = macd(close, 5, 10, 1)
plot(signalLine_1, color=color.gray)
plot(histLine_1, color=color.black, style=plot.style_columns)

// Setup MACD 2
[macdLine_2, signalLine_2, histLine_2] = macd(close, 12, 18, 1)
plot(signalLine_2, color=color.red)
plot(histLine_2, color=color.red, style=plot.style_histogram)

// Setup EMA/MA
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ma4 = sma(close, 4)

// Setup Heikin Ashi Candles
ha_open = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
ha_high = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
ha_low = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
ha_close = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)

// MA Confirmations
long_ma_ema_crossover = crossover(ma4, ema50)
short_ma_ema_crossover = crossunder(ma4, ema50)

// Heikin Ashi Confirmations
flat_bottom = low == open // BUY
flat_top = high == open // SELL
long_entry_candle = false

// MACD Confirmations
long_macd = crossover(signalLine_1, 0)
short_macd = crossunder(signalLine_1, 0)

// DMI Confirmations
high_momentum = crossover(adx, 50)
sellers_market = minus > plus
buyers_market = plus > minus

// Entry for long position if all confirmations below are true
if (long_ma_ema_crossover and flat_bottom and long_macd and high_momentum and buyers_market)
    strategy.entry("Long", true)
    plotshape(flat_bottom, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, transp=50) // Flat Bottom Candle
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because its the local scope. You should use something like that:

```
plotshape((long_ma_ema_crossover and flat_bottom and long_macd and high_momentum and buyers_market) ? flat_bottom : na, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, transp=50)
```

(you cannot plot in an if statement, so exclude it)